# How can I input a time without resulting to like this -> "2000-01-01 08:00:00"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

how can i input or select time without resulting to like this => "2000-01-01 08:00:00" if i select 08:00AM the output must be '08:00AM' on the database..the user must input only time...

**new.html.rb**

```
<%= form_for @search, html: {class: "pure-form"} do |s| %>
  <%= s.time_select :search %>
<% end %>
```

**schema.rb**

```
 create_table "searches", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.time     "search"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 end
```

Comment: @MichaelGaskill problem edited/updated.

Comment: just convert your date after getting it from the database. storing datetime as a string doesn't make sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'date'

date = DateTime.parse("2000-01-01 08:00:00")
formatted_date = date.strftime('%I:%M%p')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby and Rails don't have any data type that would define just the time fraction of a day. Even the [`Time` class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html) in Ruby is defined as *"an abstraction of dates and times"*. So, inside your rails code, you will always see the **time as a part of the default date** which is (Jan 1st, 2000).

However, since you use the `time` data type column in your database, the date part of the datetime will be thrown away when stored and **only the time will be stored** indeed.

So, the whole issue is, I think, only about the need to mentally ignore the date part of of the datetimes in your Rails code. In the view layer, as well as DB it should be correct.